# Error pushing object to base class array object in Angular application

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 5 application and have data coming in JSON format. I need create instance of class of specific type depending on variable 'QuestionElementType' type. for example if type is textbox then specific record of TextboxQuestion class, in case is dropdown then DropdownQuestion class and so on and finally push these object to type of base class that is let questions2: QuestionBase[];

in following attempt I am getting error at code questions2.push(_textBox);

### error

```
block scoped variable used before its declaration
```

### Angular class

```
let questions2: QuestionBase<any>[];

for(var key in questionsList)
{
  let questionElementType = questionsList[key].questionElement.questionElementType[0].typeDefination;      

  if(questionElementType=="textbox")
  {       
    var _textBox =

      new TextboxQuestion({
      key: 'firstName',
      label: 'First name',
      value: 'Bombasto',
      required: true,
      order: 5
     }); 

     console.log("_textBox",_textBox);

     questions2.push(_textBox);

  }
  else  if(questionElementType=="dropdown")
  {
      new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'How you Rate New steel X technology for industrial construction ',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        order: 1
      })
  }
}
```

I need final result as

```
let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [

      new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'How you Rate New steel X technology for industrial construction ',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        order: 1
      }),
      //... other types here following;
  ]
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error ? I am unable to reproduce with your code.

Comment: under Angular Class heading, look for 'questions2.push(_textBox);'

Comment: If I use strict, I get `Variable 'questions2' is used before being assigned`, which is true, and you should  do  `let questions2: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];` but I don't get your  error

Answer (score 0):

You should post your whole stack trace, not only a few words. We're not psychics you know.

Also, you should post your whole code, not only the part you want. If you don't know your error, then you probably don't know the piece of code it is coming from, so post your whole code in order for us to search in it.

First issue I see is that you use `questions2.push`, but questions2 is undefined.

Your error indicates that you are using a variable that hasn't been declared yet.

You can find [**more information here**](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17653).